# how to subtract two dates in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem. I want to subtract a date from currect date example:

Result = Today - MySpeficied Date

Can any one help me with a code snippet?

Many Thanks.
Best Regards,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at NSDate and timeIntervalSinceDate:.